# Best Practice for Personas and Pattern Cards

Tags: user-profile

I'm experimenting with the best route to setting up personas as pattern cards when they span multiple profiles. Is it possible to "share" pattern matches across profiles?

For example, if I have three profiles configured in Marketing Control Panel as follows:

**Activity Interest**

- Cycling
- Running
- Swimming

**Content Focus**

- Performance
- Aesthetics

**Content Type**

- Text
- Video
- Photo

I wanted a pattern match for different personas e.g.:

- Bob the thinking Cyclist (100% cycling - 90% performance content - 90% Text content type)
- Sue the time poor Triathlete (33% cycle/run/swim, 70% aesthetics content focus, 90% video content type)

I want Sitecore to report and personalise on how many Bob's and Sue's are on my site ... but the pattern match is created underneath each profile.

Do I have to duplicate Bob and Sue in the Pattern Cards for each profile?

Or am I missing something fundamental?

Thanks
Travis